# What is this CSS active menu style with triangle called?

Tags: css, geometry

In the following picture, I have mocked up a CSS active menu styling I would like to find examples of, and hopefully replicate.

[image: Triangle active menu]

You will notice there is a triangle highlighting the active menu, and it can appear bold too.

Question 1. What is this "active menu triangle style" actually called?  So I can find CSS examples of it.

Question 2. Where can I find examples of this?

Comment: BBC iPlayer has this effect but I am not sure how they did it, I think it was just a series of images. But either way the following answers were very helpful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All done through css classes like so:

**html**

```
<ul>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 1</li>
    <li><a href="#" class="selected">Menu Item 2</li>
    <li><a href="#">Menu Item 3</li>
    ....
</ul>
```

**css**

```
ul li a {padding: 6px; border-bottom: 1px solid #666; background-image: none; color: #454545}

ul li a.selected { background: #fff url(triangle.png) no-repeat center bottom}
```

Tweak the background-position until it fits snuggly with the border.

Answer (score 6):

I don't know how it is called, but I guess it does not correspond to any CSS property. You'll have to achieve this with background images I think.

Answer (score 5):

I don't think there's a name for this, but it's going to be hard to make this in CSS without having to add a background image. With images it's fairly easy, see the other comments.

You could of course use `:after` with some CSS3 tricks to create an element simulating the arrow, like this:

http://jsfiddle.net/upeRE/2/

But it won't work in every browser and you'd have to know exactly how wide your menu items are.

Comment: I explained what I did here on my blog if anyone's interested or has any additions: http://www.stephanmuller.nl/css3-active-menu-item-triangle/

Answer (score 2):

The shape is called a CSS polygon. [Tantek Celik](http://tantek.com/CSS/Examples/polygons.html) was one of the first to write about the technique in 2001. The design pattern is called a [location-based breadcrumb](http://www.smashingmagazine.com/2009/03/17/breadcrumbs-in-web-design-examples-and-best-practices-2/).

Answer (score 1):

You need to look for css triangles menus (or css3 triangles). 
These are made with borders that are transparent. 
There is a good explanation of how you can make the triangles here:

http://jonrohan.me/guide/css/creating-triangles-in-css/