# Icon to move when hovering over a menu button

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Before you read this please get up this website to see what I am trying to do:

https://www.kris-willis.com

As you can see there is a RED arrow located below the menu and what it is that I'm trying to achieve is... when I hover over a menu button the arrow moves to the same button I'm hovering over without reloading the page.

Ideally I'd like the arrow to move back to a default button.. and also for the default button to change if clicked on a different menu button.

If you know any links to examples etc... I would really appreciate it!

Thank you for your time,

Kerry x

Comment: SSL error on the link...

Comment: @NuclearGhost It will work if you just type the link into your browser :)

Comment: @Snuffleupagus I have tried building it from scratch using javascript but I keep failing so was wondering if there are similar things out there that I can learn off.

Comment: Don't use table for menu. Also, see [this](http://www.bloggertipandtrick.net/best-17-quality-jquery-navigation-menus/).

Comment: Do you want the arrow to /move/ to the button or /jump/ to the button?

Comment: @Llepwryd the arrow to move :)

Answer (score 0):

Make the "buttons" anchors. Using css set create a rule for `:hover` to set a background image that contains the arrow.

There are plenty of CSS tutorials out there, [Nettuts](http://net.tutsplus.com) and [Webdesigntuts](http://webdesign.tutsplus.com) have a lot of navigation articles. Or if you are comfortable with emulating others, find  a site you like and pick apart the source until you figure out how they did it.

Keep in mind that javascript is not at all necessary to accomplish what you are doing. Unless you want some animations, and even then CSS can handle most of that work, pure CSS in my opinion is the better approach.

Answer (score 0):

Just move the arrow by`margin-left` with respect to left of the `td` **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/uyehuw/7/edit)**

```
$("#Arrow").css({"margin-left":$(this).position().left+($(this).width()/2)-2});
```

Tp do this Add **[jQuery](http://jquery.com/)** libirary to the head section of your page

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Add this code in a external js file and add it to head section of your page

```
$(function(){
  $("#MenuPosition").on("hover","td",function(){
    $("#Arrow").css({"margin-left":$(this).position().left+($(this).width()/2)-2});

  });

});
```

**EDIT :** For restoring the arrow orignal position use

```
$(function(){
  currentPos = $("#Arrow").css("margin-left");

  $("#MenuPosition").on("hover","td",function(){
    $("#Arrow").css({"margin-left":$(this).position().left});

  });


   $("#MenuPosition").on("mouseout","td",function(){

     $("#Arrow").css({"margin-left":currentPos});        
  });

});
```

**NOTE :** PLEASE SEE THE CALCULATION PART AND CORRECT IT.

PS: cant correct is because its my log out time from office ;) . but i thing you got the logic to do it

Comment: Is there a way of setting a default button for the arrow to move back to once the mouse is off the button ?

Answer (score 0):

The first thing is that you have a wrong DOCTYPE.

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "">
```

This causes you page to load in quirk mode. Change it to

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

for HTML5 or use the complete one including the FSI & FPI.

Second is you are using a `<table>` for navigation. Nothing seriously wrong with it but people tend to use `ul`

For the `:hover`, you can simply use

```
#MenuPosition table tbody tr td:hover
{
background-image: url("/images/Arrow.jpg");
}
```

You might have to play with `paddings` and `margins` or maybe use `display: block` or `display: inline-block` to position the arrow correctly.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4416805/what-is-this-css-active-menu-style-with-triangle-called

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this:

Using a span to add the bg arrow below the nav/menu lis in the HTML:

```
<ul class="nav">
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 1</a>
        <span class="arrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
    <li>
        <a href="#">Menu 2</a>
        <span class="arrow">&nbsp;&nbsp;</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

The CSS:

```
.nav {
    font-size: anypx;
    list-style: none outside none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    position: relative;
}

.nav li {
    background: #whatev;
    display: block;
    float: left;
    height: anypx;
    line-height: anypx;
    padding: 0;
    text-align: center;
}

.nav li a {
    color: #any;
    display: block;
    padding: any;
    position: relative;
    text-decoration: none;
    width: auto;
}
.arrow {
    background: url("images/arrow.png") no-repeat scroll 0 9px transparent;
    display: none;
    height: anypx;
    text-indent: -9999px;
    width: whatevs;
    z-index: 9999;
}
```

And Finally the JS/Jquery that makes it work:

```
$(document).ready(function(){     
    Your_menu();
});

function Your_menu(){

    $(".nav li").hover(function(){
            $(this).find('.arrow').css({visibility: "visible",display: "none"}).show();
        },function(){
            $(this).find('.arrow').css({visibility: "hidden"});
    });

}
```

Here is a site that is showing this :)

http://www.drexelmedicine.org/

Answer (score 0):

**PURE CSS SOLUTION**

Check this answer.

[Is there any way to hover over one element and affect a different element?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6867257/is-there-any-way-to-hover-over-one-element-and-effect-a-different-element)

So it might be:

```
#thething {
    margin: 0;
}
.classone:hover + #thething {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-left: 10px;
}
```

If they're adjacent siblings in a parent div.